Is $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q} = 0$?
Given the abelian group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and the group $\mathbb{Q}$, is it true that their tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}$ is the trivial group, i.e., $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q} = 0$?
I have considered $\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ such that $b$ does not divide $a$, and $\frac {c}{d}\in\mathbb{Q}$
\begin{equation*}
\frac{a}{b}\otimes \frac{c}{d}=\frac{ad}{bd}\otimes\frac{c}{d}
=\frac{a}{bd}\otimes\frac{cd}{d}=\frac{a}{bd}\otimes c=\frac{ac}{bd}\otimes 1
\end{equation*}
Is the tensor product $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Q}$ indeed correct?

It's better not to write elements of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ as $\frac{a}{b}$, this only causes confusion. It's not difficult to write $\frac{a}{b}+\mathbb{Z}$.

Are you ok with
$$(\frac12+\Bbb{Z})\otimes\frac13=(\frac12+\Bbb{Z})\otimes2\cdot\frac16=2(\frac12+\Bbb{Z})\otimes\frac13=0\otimes\frac13$$
because $2(\frac12+\Bbb{Z})=1+\Bbb{Z}=0+\Bbb{Z}=0_{\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}}$?

No, this is incorrect. All the relations you wrote down are true, but there are more relations, because
$$
\frac{a}{b} \otimes \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a}{b} \otimes \frac{bc}{bd} = \frac{ba}{b} \otimes \frac{c}{bd} = 0 \otimes \frac{c}{bd} = 0.
$$
In fact, any divisible abelian group, tensored with any torsion abelian group, is zero, by the same proof.

It's better not to write elements of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ as $\frac{a}{b}$, this only causes confusion. Of course, this is first of all a comment to OP.

n i c e . . . .
